# SharePoint 2013 Custom file properties update using rest

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to update custom document properties for a file in SharePoint 2013 using REST and JavaScript

```
function uploadFileProp() 
{
             $.ajax({
                url: "https://sp/sites/xxxx/_api/web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/xxxx/ta/cs_architecture_3_0.png')/ListItemAllFields",
                type: "POST",
                 data: "{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.ListItem' }, 'OperatingGroup': 'New' }",
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                    "X-HTTP-Method":"Merge"
                },
                complete: function (data) {
                    alert('succes');
                },
                error: function (err) {
                     alert('failed');
                }
        });
}
```

But it is not updating my custom property.

Response :

> {"error":{"code":"-1,
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Invalid
>   request."}}}

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs since invalid header value is specified for [X-HTTP-Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd541471.aspx):

> The syntax of the X-HTTP-Method is defined as follows:
>
> ```
> XHTTPMethod  =   "X-HTTP-Method: " 
>                 ("PUT" 
>                 / "MERGE" 
>                 / "PATCH"
>                 / "DELETE") 
>                 CRLF
> ```

Replace  `"X-HTTP-Method":"Merge"` with `"X-HTTP-Method":"MERGE"`.

Unfortunately this is not the only issue of specified example:

- [If-Match](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd541480.aspx) header is a **mandatory** for update operation
- most probably the entity type name is incorrect (`SP.ListItem`) since
  you are updating list item of a *Library*

Below is demonstrated how to update File properties

> Note: you don't have to specify entity type name explicitly since it
>   is determined automatically

```
function updateFileProperties(webUrl,fileUrl,properties) 
{
    var endpointUrl = webUrl + "/_api/web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl('" + fileUrl + "')/ListItemAllFields";
    return executeJson(endpointUrl).then(function(data){
        var updateHeaders = {
            'X-HTTP-Method' : 'MERGE',
            'If-Match': data.d['__metadata']['etag']
        };
        var itemPayload = properties;
        itemPayload['__metadata'] = {'type': data.d['__metadata']['type']};
        return executeJson(endpointUrl,'POST',updateHeaders,itemPayload);    
    });
}

function executeJson(url,method,headers,payload) 
{
    method = method || 'GET';
    headers = headers || {};
    headers["Accept"] = "application/json;odata=verbose";
    if(method == "POST") {
        headers["X-RequestDigest"] = $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val();
    }      
    var ajaxOptions = 
    {       
       url: url,   
       type: method,  
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       headers: headers
    };
    if (typeof payload != 'undefined') {
      ajaxOptions.data = JSON.stringify(payload);
    }  
    return $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
}
```

**Usage**

Update `Title` property of File located under `Documents` library:

```
var webUrl = 'https://contoso.sharepoint.com';
var fileUrl = '/Documents/SharePoint User Guide.docx';
var properties = {
    'Title': 'New title',
};

updateFileProperties(webUrl,fileUrl,properties)
   .done(function(){
       console.log('File has been updated');    
   })
   .fail(function(error){
       console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
   });
```